# References on natural topology in full binary rooted trees

Tags: reference-request, order-theory, trees

I am working in the context of binary rooted trees and I think I am probably reinventing the wheel with a large part of what I am doing.

More precisely, consider a full binary rooted tree $(T,<)$ (where $<$ is the tree order) such that every chain in $(T,<)$ has a supremum. (for instance $2^{\leq\omega}$ where $u<v$ iff $u$ is an initial segment of $u$)

I am looking at the topology on $(T,<)$ whose closed sets are those which are stable under suprema of non-empty chains.

Where can I find literature about such structures?

Comment: I can't claim to fully understand your question but there's an isomorphism between the tree and $\{-1,1\}\times\Bbb{Z}(2^{\infty})$ which may give you a topology derived from $\Bbb{Z}_2$.  Start with $0$ as the root and make the left child relation $T_L(x)=x-2^{v_2\left(\tfrac{x}{2}\right)}$ and make the right child relation $T_R=x+2^{v_2\left(\tfrac{x}{2}\right)}$. By this method you will construct the positive and negative dyadic rationals in the interval $(-1,1)$

Comment: @ProducerofBS I am not sure I understand you either. Are you assuming that the tree is $2^{<\omega}$?

Comment: I don't know!  But if I were to make an educated guess I would say the dyadic rationals in the interval $(-1,1)$ are $2^{<\omega}$ and their limits which can be thought of as two copies of $\Bbb{Z}_2$ are $2^{\leq\omega}$.  With their discrete topology they are the Pontryagin dual of the 2-adic integers as it mentions here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_group